# Is it true I can't edit a MySQL trigger, I have to drop it and create a new one?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is it true I can't edit a MySQL trigger, I have to drop it and create a new one?

Also, being a relative newcomer to triggers, it feels like they seem liable to causing 'erroneous' data. For example I might want a trigger to be fired (inserting data into another table) after one particular type of update query, but not others.

Any tips here gratefully received!

Comment: I found this helpful for implementation https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78438/is-it-possible-to-modify-an-existing-trigger-definition-in-mysql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:** Yes, it is true that versions 5.n and 6.n of MySQL 5 & 6 implement `CREATE TRIGGER` and `DROP TRIGGER` and nothing else.  According to [this hunk of Postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/files/documentation/books/aw_pgsql/node223.html), there is not even `CREATE TRIGGER` in SQL 92, so consider yourself lucky to have TRIGGER at all :-)

The [Visual Studio MySQL plugin documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-vstudio-using-triggers.html) has:

> To modify an existing trigger, double click on a node of the trigger you wish to modify, or right click on this node and choose the Alter Trigger command from a context menu. Either of the commands opens the SQL Editor.

... which seems to do what you want.  My guess is this is GUI sugar and behind the scenes you get a `DROP CREATE`.

As far as a trigger for some `UPDATE`s and not others, SQL has exactly one `UPDATE` per table.  Put an `IF` clause at the start of your `UPDATE` trigger so that your logic - whatever you are doing in some of your `UPDATE`s - is only executed when you think it is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for that, had spotted that article on my travels. I'm not using the Visual Studio plug in though. :( seems harsh I can't edit the actions in a trigger once created. Still nevermind!

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has REPLACE TRIGGER, right?

As a sidenote.. Is it an issue? If you're worried queries are executed in between DROP and CREATE, you could always lock the table beforehand.

Comment: Can you lock the table??  In MySQL all DDL statements implicitly commit the transaction.  Unless I'm mistaken, the locks would be released by the DROP TRIGGER...

Comment: I take that back.  I looked into it, and it seems that locks will not be released by DROP TRIGGER or CREATE TRIGGER statements.  It's explained here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **MySql Workbench** it will allow you to alter the trigger. Just right click on your table name and click Alter table option from there you can pick Trigger option and alter it. Although, you cannot perform it from query mode.
`Table Name --> Right Click --> Alter Table --> Triggers`.