# Can you modify an existing mysql trigger after it has been created?

Tags: mysql, triggers

In `mysql` I can create a trigger, and then show information about it like this:

```
mysql> show triggers like 'fooTrigger';
```

This command gives output that looks an awful lot like a select statement, with a row showing the matching trigger.  Is it possible to update a column on the row it shows me?

For example, one column is named `Statement`, and it defines what happens when the trigger is activated.  Is it possible to change the `Statement` field for `fooTrigger` so the trigger does something different?  Or do I need to `drop` and re-`create` the trigger?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717711/is-it-true-i-cant-edit-a-mysql-trigger-i-have-to-drop-it-and-create-a-new-one

Comment: I think one of these questions could be closed, but I *did* try searching for this answer before asking the question, and I didn't find the one linked above.  Would it be a good idea to change or add some wording to the other question to make it more findable?

Comment: Hmmm, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates, looks like we should probably just close this, and then users will still be able to find the answer to their question regardless of wording.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As of MySQL 5.5, you must drop and re-create the trigger.
It is not possible to update the `Statement` column without dropping the trigger.

Documentation: [CREATE TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html) [DROP TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/drop-trigger.html)

You may also access information about triggers using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS
```

But, as these tables are actually views, you can't use `UPDATE` on them.
It's just a more convenient way to access and manipulate the information than using SHOW TRIGGERS.

Documentation: [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers-table.html)

Comment: New to working with TRIGGERS so take this with a grain of salt, but this looks to still holds true with MySQL 8.* (see answer comment)
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78438/is-it-possible-to-modify-an-existing-trigger-definition-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

As @Jocelyn mentioned you can't alter the trigger. But if you're using **MySql Workbench** it will allow you to alter the trigger. Just right click on your table name and click Alter table option from there you can pick Trigger option and alter it. Although you cannot perform it from query.
Table Name --> Alter Table --> Triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You may require, on Windows OS, ***[Connector/Net Visual Studio Integration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net-visual-studio.html)*** to view and edit existing database object. Limitation is that you can only [*edit trigger*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net-visual-studio-editing-triggers.html) body within `For each row ...` loop.

Otherwise only option one has is drop and re create the trigger.
But make sure before dropping a trigger that the table associated with a trigger is locked and
and unlocked after trigger is re-created.