# What is the right way to modify a MySQL trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

As you probably know, there's no syntax that modifies a MySQL trigger.

To do that, you need to execute DROP TRIGGER and then re-create it again with the new definition.

What is the right/best way of doing this, considering the following:

- You cannot encapsulate these two statements in a transaction as that will be pointless (both DROP TRIGGER and CREATE TRIGGER invoke implicit transactions)
- You cannot use LOCK TABLES READ as an error is triggered
- Just between your DROP and CREATE TRIGGER, some other session might insert/update/delete row(s) which won't be handled by neither of your new nor old triggers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you modify an existing mysql trigger after it has been created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525930/can-you-modify-an-existing-mysql-trigger-after-it-has-been-created)

Comment: You're in stuck. Another reason to consider starting using postgresql.

Comment: It's not a duplicate at all, I and many other people know we can modify a MySQL trigger but not using a single statement. So the question is 'what is the best for doing that'

Comment: About to try it, but confirming the answer looks good 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78438/is-it-possible-to-modify-an-existing-trigger-definition-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing before I posted, I overlooked what type of LOCK I'm acquiring, it was READ.

So it seems using **WRITE** lock does the job:

```
delimiter $$

LOCK TABLES table1 WRITE $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_insert_on_table1 $$

CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_on_table1 AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        ...
    END
$$

UNLOCK TABLES $$

delimiter ;
```

So my recommendation is to always use this sequence when updating/modifying triggers.

Comment: I guess you shouldn't forget to `UNLOCK TABLES $$` before the last `delimiter ;`?

Comment: @mgarciaisaia thanks, corrected. The truth is it is working for me as when you close the session all lock are automatically released